# Having trouble with adding multiple buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, screenshot

I'm trying to add multiple buttons in one Flash file (as most Flash files have).

Here is the code:

```
stop();

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var buttonName:String = event.currentTarget.name;
    if(buttonName == "playButton"){
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else if(buttonName == "settingsButton"){
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }

}
```

So what is happening is the play button works fine, but the settings button does not.

Also, later I'm going to transfer all that code to an ActionScript file, and use the `include` thing on the frame that everything is on at the moment, so no need to tell me that code on the timeline is bad (which I don't understand; can someone please explain that as a bonus? No need, it'd just be nice).

If I just do this:

```
stop();

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
settingsButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var buttonName:String = event.currentTarget.name;
    if(buttonName == "playButton"){
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else if(buttonName == "settingsButton"){
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }

}
```

I get error 1009:

```
TypeError: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Comment: So, what is your problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Dear god I'm stupid. Here's the edit I made to the post: EDIT: TOTALLY forgot to state my PROBLEM. Ok, so what is happening is the play button works fine, but the settings button does not. Sorry for being such an idiot, I'm facepalming so much right now ;(.

Answer (score 1):

You did not really state your problem. But if you want to add multiple buttons then just add the event listener to multiple buttons and it's done.

```
playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
settingsButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
```

Comment: Dear god I'm stupid. Here's the edit I made to the post: EDIT: TOTALLY forgot to state my PROBLEM. Ok, so what is happening is the play button works fine, but the settings button does not. Sorry for being such an idiot, I'm facepalming so much right now ;(.

Comment: You did not add the event listener to the settingsButton, also, the instance name is case sensitive so be sure that it's the same.

Comment: I did what you said and I get error #1009, Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: Means that the `settingsButton` does not exist in the current context, did you put the button in a container? Like another movieclip or sprite? If so, then you must give that one an instance name and access it in the following way: `parentInstanceName.settingsButton`